# Angular router not redirecting to the component specified with the path

Tags: angular, router, angular4-router

I have a small application with 2 components, Comp1 and Comp2, where Comp2 has a child component Comp2Child.

I am trying to redirect to and load component1 on click of a button in component2. Even if the url changes to /comp1, still component2 HTML is rendered in the view.

Here is the code-

**Routing**-

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'comp1', component: Comp1Component },
  { path: '', component: Comp2Component, children: [
      { path: 'child', component: Comp2ChildComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

**app.module.ts**-

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    Comp1Component,
    Comp2Component,
    Comp2ChildComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    Comp2Component
  ],
  providers: [
    NewService
  ]
})
```

**comp2.html**-

```
<p>
  comp2 works!
</p>
<button (click)="m1()">Emit</button>
```

**comp2.ts**-

```
export class Comp2Component implements OnInit {

   constructor(private newService: NewService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('comp2 init');
  }

  m1() {
    // this.newService.e1.emit('e1');
    // this.newService.s1.next('s1');
    this.router.navigate(['comp1']);
  }
}
```

**comp1.ts**-

```
export class Comp1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private newService: NewService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('comp1 init');
    this.newService.e1.subscribe((res1) => {
      console.log('e1 res in comp1 emitted from comp2: ', res1);
    });
    this.newService.s1.subscribe((res2) => {
      console.log('s1 res in comp1 emitted from comp2: ', res2);
    });
  }

}
```

When application loads, Component2 loads as part of bootstrapping. When I click on the button in comp2.html, the url changes to /comp1, but view still says **comp2 works**.

[image: Check this image]

Comment: Try adding slash `this.router.navigate(['/comp1']);`

Comment: Where is your router-outlet?

Answer (score 0):

To see the view of `comp2` you must have a router outlet, which can hold the view of currently active routes.

In Your `comp2.html`, put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` somewhere, and see it should show the view of other components too.

**But, that's gonna give you another trouble that, `comp2` will still be present there !! And you must be knowing now how to get rid of that.**